# Enviar dados para o Banco de Dados de acordo com a tag <select> via PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Estou fazendo um formulário para enviar alguns dados para o banco, para agilizar um processo, minha dúvida é a seguinte, eu tenho 5 sistemas que preciso atualizar, então fiz um `select` em html.   
 
Eu preciso enviar cada `option` do `select` para uma tabela do banco diferente, por exemplo, se eu selecionar o **"Sistema 1"** ele vai pra tabela **"Sistema 1"** no banco, se for **"Sistema 2"** na tabela **"Sistema 2"** e assim por diante, em cada tabela teria os mesmo campos só mudaria o nome, para depois eu listar ela em outra tela do site.  
 
 
Qual seria o jeito mais simples de eu fazer isso em PHP ?   
 
 [image: Print do formulário]

```
<div class="form-group">
        <form action="envia.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><b>Sistema</b></label>    
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select name="sistema" class="form-control" required/>
                        <option>Escolha o sistema que deseja importar</option>
                        <option value="sis1">Sistema 1</option>
                        <option value="sis2">Sistema 2</option>
                        <option value="sis3">Sistema 3</option>
                        <option value="sis4">Sistema 4</option>
                        <option value="sis5">Sistema 5</option>
                        <option value="sis6">Sistema 6</option>
                        <option value="sis7">Sistema 7</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Deixa o nome da tabela dinamico na query. Aí ele vai inserir na tabela que for escolhida pelo select

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso ? Só pra eu ter uma base de pesquisa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Levando em conta que você está realizando um `POST` e que o `<select>` possua a seguinte sintaxe:

```
<select name="sistema">
    <option selected>Selecione uma opção* </option>
    <option value="sistema1" > Sistema 1 </option>
    <option value="sistema2" > Sistema 2 </option>
    <option value="sistema3" > Sistema 3 </option>
    <option value="sistema4" > Sistema 4 </option>
    <option value="sistema5" > Sistema 5 </option>
</select>
```

A sacada é inserir o nome das tabelas no valor das opções e capturá-lo no `PHP`.

No seu `PHP` ficaria assim:

```
$table = addslashes($_POST['sistema']); //nome da tabela
```

E na hora de montar sua `query`, ficaria algo parecido com:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $table (campo1, campo2, campo3) VALUES (valor1, valor2, valor3)";
```

Caso não queira passar o nome das tabelas diretamente nos `options`, passe nomes genéricos e trate no `PHP`.

Exemplo:

```
<select name="sistema">
        <option selected>Selecione uma opção* </option>
        <option value="table1" > Sistema 1 </option>
        <option value="table2" > Sistema 2 </option>
        <option value="table3" > Sistema 3 </option>
        <option value="table4" > Sistema 4 </option>
        <option value="table5" > Sistema 5 </option>
    </select>
```

No `PHP`:

```
$table = addslashes($_POST['sistema']);

switch($table) {
    case 'table1':
        $table = 'sistema1'; //definindo o valor da table como sistema1 (nome da tabela)
    break;
    case 'table2':
        $table = 'sistema2'; //definindo o valor da table como sistema2 (nome da tabela)
    break;
    case 'table3':
        $table = 'sistema3'; //definindo o valor da table como sistema3 (nome da tabela)
    break;
    case 'table4':
        $table = 'sistema4'; //definindo o valor da table como sistema4 (nome da tabela)
    break;
    case 'table5':
        $table = 'sistema5'; //definindo o valor da table como sistema5 (nome da tabela)
    break;
}

$query = "INSERT INTO $table (campo1, campo2, campo3) VALUES (valor1, valor2, valor3)";
```

Como não informou a sua estrutura, fiz um exemplo mais genérico possível.

Comment: eu editei minha pergunta e coloquei a estrutura, mas é basicamente isso que você comentou, como estou usando o action em outro arquivo, eu faço toda a parte de php no meu arquivo envia.php, certo ? Qualquer dúvida, volto a comentar.

Comment: @lucasecorrea exatamente, toda parte do `php` será feita dentro do arquivo que você está enviando os dados.

Comment: @lucasecorrea editei e acrescentei um novo exemplo, dê uma olhada

Comment: me ajudou bastante a explicação, só tirar mais uma dúvida, eu vou precisar passar 2 campos do formulário para o banco (http://prntscr.com/lf2zlb) que estão com esses nome do print, lá no php eu preciso criar duas váriaveis para passar gravar as informações no banco? (http://prntscr.com/lf3111). Dá uma olhada nos prints e me fiz se to no caminho certo.

Comment: Isso mesmo, você ira capturar todos os campos enviados via POST, do jeito que fez está correto.

Comment: só mais uma dúvida boba, estou usando phpmyadmin, se eu criar um campo de uma tabela do banco do tipo DATE o padrão vai ser aaaa-mm-dd lá no phpmyadmin, se digitar no meu formulário no padrão dd-mm-aaaa, tem algum jeito de converter para cair correto no banco ?

Comment: Basta receber o dado e tratar antes de enviar para o banco. `$date = addslashes(date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['date']))));` dessa forma faz o tratamento e substitui todos os "\" por "-" para salvar no banco.

Comment: Cara to tentando fazer com explode, implode e desse jeito que você mandou mas ta dando erro, o erro é esse que retornei ali em baixo. Esse é o print de como está o PHP (http://prntscr.com/lf5jab). Onde estou errando ?

Comment: (http://prntscr.com/lf5lbf) o banco está montado assim

Comment: Qual é o erro?? De um var_dump($_POST['data']); e depois um var_dump($data) e veja como está vindo. Lembrnado que o uso do str_replace é aplicado apenas se sua data estiver vindo nesse formato do front: `'01/01/2018`

Comment: (http://prntscr.com/lf62i4) O var_dump trouxe isso, no form ta vindo dessa maneira você disse, (http://prntscr.com/lf631i) está com mascara para `00/00/9999`. Tentei de várias tratar essa data para salvar corretamente no banco mas não consegui.

Comment: O erro está falando que a variável data não foi declarada.  Revise as linhas 144 e 170. Obs: tire o $data = $_POST['data'] pois vc ja tem esse dado na linha seguinte.

Comment: (http://prntscr.com/lf69qo) coloquei o que você tinha me mandado antes e não salvou no banco, o único erro que deu foi esse destacado ali abaixo no print

Comment: Recomendo envolver seu código dentro de um bloco try catch para saber se o problema é na hora de inserir

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$select = $_POST['seu_select'];

switch ($select) {
    case 0:
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabela1(campo1,campo2,campo3) VALUES ('valor1', 'valor2', 'valor3')";
    mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

    break;

    case 1:
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabela2(campo1,campo2,campo3) VALUES ('valor1', 'valor2', 'valor3')";
    mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
    break;

    case 2:
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tabela3(campo1,campo2,campo3) VALUES ('valor1', 'valor2', 'valor3')";
    mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
    break;
}

?>
```

Comment: Essa gambiarra quebraria um galho ? Pq é um sistema interno aqui na empresa então pode ser bem simples. Uma dúvida, onde você colocou 'seu_input' seria o nome do select ?

Comment: exatamente, e conforme o valor retornado ele entra no case responsável por pelo seu valor, essa é uma forma simples de fazer tudo tratamento pelo php, e para iniciantes também

Comment: Não precisa montar a query em cada case, apenas pegue o nome da table e monte a query no final.

Comment: Exatamente isso

Answer (score 0):

se o `name` do seu `<select>` for tabela faça assim:

```
$sql="INSERT into `".$_POST[tabela]."` set campo1='".$_POST[var1]."'";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

obs: isso caso você esteja utilizando o `mysqli` se for mysql apenas

```
$sql="INSERT into `".$_POST[tabela]."` set campo1='".$_POST[var1]."'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

onde `campo1` é um ex você pode inserir os nomes dos campos da sua tabela e os `names` como variavel, eo `method` do seu formulário tem que estar como `post`

Comment: $sql="INSERT into SISTEMA1".$_POST[tabela]."` set versao='".$_POST[?????]." ?????'";
mysql_query($sql);

Sou meio iniciante com PHP, seria mais ou menos isso ? e onde eu coloquei os pontos de interrogação o que eu teria que colocar ali ? e nos option eu teria que colocar algum valor para passar de parametro ?